# DAO and Service layer design

Tags: java, java-ee-6

I am developing web application with Java EE 6. In order to minimize calls to database will it be a good idea to have classes:

Data access class (DAO) will call only basic methods `getAllClients, getAllProducts, getAllOrders, delete, update` methods - CRUD methods.

Service class which will call CRUD methods but in addition filter methods e.g. `findClientByName, findProuctByType, findProductByYear, findOrderFullyPaid/NotPaid` etc... which will be based on basic DAO methods.

Thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In my experience (albeit, limited) `DAO` classes tend to have all the possible database operations which the application is allowed to perform. So in your case, it will have methods such as `getAllClients()` and `getClientByName(String name)`, etc.

Getting all the users in your DAO and iterating all over them until you find the one you need will result in unneeded waste of computational time and memory consumption.

If you want to reduce the amount of times that your database is hit you could, maybe, implement some caching mechanism. An [ORM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping) framework such as [Hibernate](http://www.hibernate.org/) should be able to provide what you need as shown [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/hibernate/hibernate_caching.htm).

EDIT:

As per your comment question, no, your service will not be made redundant. What one does is to usually use a `Service` layer to expose the `DAO` functionalities. This will, basically, not make the `DAO` visible from the from front end of your application. It usually also allows for extra methods, such as, for instance, `public String getUserFormatted(String userName)`. This will make use of the `getUserByName` function offered by the `DAO` but provide some extra functionality.

The `Service` layer will also make itself useful should there be a change in specification and you now also need a web service to interface with your application. Having a service layer in between will allow the web service to query the `DAO` through the `Service` layer.

So basically, the `DAO` layer will still *worry* about the database stuff (CRUD Operations) while the service will adapt the data returned by the `DAO` without exposing the DAO.

Comment: Will my Service class be redundant then, because I will have java beans classes as well?

Comment: so Service class will be appropriate for method which generates pdf sales report as well?

Comment: @alex: Yes you could have something like that, meaning that in the DAO you will have appropriate methods to pull the data and in the service you will have methods to construct the DAO. This will make sure that the DAO will only take care of DB operations while the Service provides other, in this case, formatting, functionalities.

Comment: @alex: No worries. Also, in my previous comments I have a typo, `in the service you will have methods to construct the DAO.` should be `in the service you will have methods to construct the report.`

Answer (score 3):

It's hard to say without more information, but I think it's probably a good idea to leverage your database more than with just CRUD operations. Databases *are good* at searching, provided you configure them correctly, so IMHO it's a good idea to let your database handle the searching in your find methods for you.  This means that your find methods would probably go in your DAOs...

It's good to think about/be aware of the implications of DB access on performance, but don't go overboard.  Also, your approach implies that since your services are going to be doing the filtering, you are going to load a large amount of DB data into your application, which is a bad idea.  The bottom line is you should use your RDBMS as it is intended to be used, and worry about performance due to over-access when you can show its a problem.  I doubt you will run into that scenario.

Answer (score 2):

I would say that you're better off having your DAO be more fine grained than you've specified.

I'd suggest putting findClientByName, findProuctByType, findProductByYear, findOrderFullyPaid/NotPaid on your DAO as well in some way because your database will most likely be better at filtering and sorting data than your in memory code.

Imagine you have 10 years of data and you call findProductsByYear on your service class and it then calls getAllProducts and then throws away 9 years of data in memory. You're far better off getting your database to only return you the year you are interested in.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is the right way to do it.

The service will own the transactions.  You should write these as POJOs; that way you can expose them as SOAO or REST web services, EJBs, or anything else that you want later on.